# Hyperledger REST Server or SDK

Tags: rest, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

With Hyperledger composer deprecated and fabric-rest-api (https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric-sdk-rest) archived, what is the future roadmap of REST API for Hyperledger fabric? What is recommended way to expose rest APIs with Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.x? The documentation (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/fabric-sdks.html) mentions that REST SDK will be provided in subsequent releases - but cannot find a roadmap.

Comment: You might get a focused answer by asking in their community channels https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/questions.html

Answer (score 0):

When you say REST api, I assume you mean a REST api to access your hyperledger fabric application ? If so then you would need to implement that yourself. As far as I know there is no plan to provide any sort of generic rest server that can access smart contracts hosted in fabric.

Answer (score 0):

There were plans to build a Hyperledger Fabric REST SDK on top of the Node.js SDK, and work was started on this. The **FABR** key tracks all related stories to it on the Hyperledger Jira tracker (see https://jira.hyperledger.org/projects/FABR).

The related repository is https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric-sdk-rest

However as you can see the project has been archived. Many people have made their own REST APIs which exposes the internal Fabric functionality through REST, including myself. Another example might be one made by Altoros (see https://github.com/Altoros/fabric-rest). The problem is that these are not always kept up to date and have questionable authentication (if any).

It's sad to say but the first thing you would have to develop to work with Hyperledger Fabric is your own set of tools.

Answer (score 0):

For a very basic example of a REST API implementation for Hyperledger Fabric with the Node.js SDK, I would like to refer to https://medium.com/@kctheservant/an-implementation-of-api-server-for-hyperledger-fabric-network-8764c79f1a87.